# Require SDK Facebook on dedicated server

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, dedicated-server

I have a little issue with a script PHP that include Facebook SDK (v4.4.0).

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

On localhost server and on a mutualized server, it's perfect, it works. But when I try to host my script on a dedicated server (Kimsufi), require function bug.

I think it's a configuration issue but I don't know how to resolve that.
Can someone help me, please ?
If you need any information...

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: I don't have any error message. The require function is just blocked. I think my dedicated server forbidden external communication but I don't know how to configure that.

Comment: It displays the echo before require function, but not one after.

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? If not do so please.

Answer (score 0):

I search logs in my dedicated server and I find a line.
My PHP version is 5.3.3 and Facebook SDK needs 5.4. I don't know how I will update my PHP version but that's the solution.

I look for a Facebook SDK (or alternative) for PHP 5.3. If you have that, I'm interested.